# XWork class loading error in startup- Unable to read class [WEB-INF

Tags: struts2, xwork

In a Struts2 application, I'm seeing this error even though there are no issues in the functionality. But I'm seeing some delay in executing every action. This delay is valid for simple actions which return a JSP page with a search box in it. I'm using Struts 2.3.1.1 and xwork-core-2.3.1.1.

```
ERROR finder.ClassFinder: Unable to read class [WEB-INF.classes.com.***.***.ConfigManagement]
Could not load WEB-INF/classes/com/***/***/ConfigManagement.class - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:785)
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Without further information it's going to be difficult to help. I'm suspicious of the `WEB-INF.classes.etc` part, but without knowing anything at all about what that class is, how/where it's used, etc. not sure what you expect.

Comment: what are steps to follow to produce above error message.

Comment: This error is repeatedly coming to all of my action classes. It finds the action classes based on my setting in the struts.xml to scan a specific package.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3703?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV, Thanks for that; I also came across this jira issue. Does this mean this issue should not come after Struts 2.2.3.1? The fact is, I'm using struts2-core-2.3.1.1 in my application :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved with the latest Struts (2.3.12) update along with the relevant library files. I should have missed some of the libraries in the previous version of the Struts.